# Can an electron borrow momentum from its field?

Tags: momentum, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

Let us consider a charged particle moving with uniform velocity $v$. We know that the EM field due to it has some momentum too. If the mass of the particle is $M$,
then the momentum of the particle is $Mv$. Why can't the particle borrow some of its momentum from the field or lend some of its momentum to the field, thereby 
increasing or reducing its velocity?

This shouldn't be a case of violation of law of conservation of momentum. But now let's take a look at law of conservation of 
energy. Here we can see the kinetic energy of the particle is changing, but it's only its field with which the exchange of momentum is going on. Should we 
consider the field of the particle as another system and can be fair by law of conservation of energy. I guess this kind of events doesn't happen. But can we have a
reason that puts restriction on it? Why is this not spontaneous, is there any kind of entropy for EM fields?

Comment: Why should it occur spontaneously? By Newton's laws, a *force* is required to induce a change in momentum, and no force acts on the uniformly moving particle.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : Why can't we take the particle and the system as a single system and consider this as an interaction between the two ? I mean we can view it as the field transferring the momentum and the particle receiving it.

Comment: Again, there is no reason any force should act, so there is no such interaction. The only way you get such an interaction is if something (like another charge) exerts a force on the moving particle, like in MarcelKöpke's answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind :Any reason why this exchange of momentum shouldn't take place . I know it seems preposterous but any rigorous reason for it ?

Comment: In classical mechanics, you don't need to give reasons why things *shouldn't* happen, you need to give reasons why they *should*. Momentum transfer means the action of a force, and there is simply nothing exerting any force for a uniformly moving single particle.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : Have just one more question ,but afraid that it might be considered as irrelevant, should I ask it in chat or here ?

Answer (score 1):

It's acutally possible. The phenomenon is called [Bremsstrahlung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) (its direct translations would be something like "stopping radiation"). It can be described purely with [classical theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) like special relativty and electromagnetism.

If a charged particle is accelerating, it "borrows" some of his momentum and energy to the EM-field which is then radiated as EM-waves carrying this momentum and energy.

Comment: Kopke : Bremsstrahlung involves the interaction of two charged particles ..but my question is about a single charged particle ...

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: Well the opposite is true, too. EM-waves/-fields can accelerate charged particles (obviously) and therefore lend some of it's momentum and energy to the particle.
I think your problem is the following: If there is a change in a particle's velocity, this is **always** due to an accleration (at least in classical theories).

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: well you changed your comment. Bremsstrahlung is not about a second particle present. It always occurs when a **single** charged particle is accelerated, no matter what caused this acceleration. The wikipedia article is quite incorrect in that statement, sorry. I looked at the [german article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) and just linked the english one

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: here the translation of the first sentence of the german article: "Bremsstrahlung is the electromagnetic radiation that arises when a charged particle, for example, an electron is accelerated. Any change in velocity of a charged particle produces radiation."

Answer (score -1):

*Why can't the particle borrow some of its momentum from the field or lend some of its momentum to the field thereby increasing or reducing its velocity?*

Because the particle *is* the field. We make an electron (and a positron) out of electromagnetic waves in [gamma-gamma pair production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics). In [atomic orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties) electrons "exist as standing waves". We can diffract electrons. In quantum field theory the electron is described as a field excitation. It isn't some billiard-ball particle that *has* a field. You can't take the electron's field away leaving some little point-particle thing. If you take away the field, there *is* no electron. For an analogy, think of a cyclone, and ask a similar question:

*Why can't the cyclone borrow some of its momentum from the rotational airflow or lend some of its momentum to the rotational airflow thereby increasing or reducing its velocity?*

Because the cyclone *is* rotational airflow. If you took away the rotational airflow, there *is* no cyclone. Having said all that, take a look at [Compton scattering](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/comptint.html). The photon gives some of its momentum to the electron's field thereby increasing its velocity.

Edit: see what Marcel said above. Bremsstrahlung is also known as the inverse Compton.

Comment: *"Because the particle is the field."*...nope. You are correct that QFT has particles as "excitations of quantum fields", but the electron is the excitation of a fermion field that has, intrinsically, nothing to do with the electric field the electron as a classical charge has. Also, gamma-gamma pair production doesn't mean that the electron is made of the EM field, just as producing photons from matter-antimatter annihiliation doesn't mean that "the photon is made out of matter".

Comment: With respect, the fermion field excitation and the classical charged particle are two different descriptions of the same physical thing, so they *are* intrinsically related. And it's quantum field theory, not quantum point-particle theory.

Comment: No, the classical description is *not* equivalent to the quantum description at all. Also, the excitation of the fermion field exists even if no electromagnetic field exists. The electric field of the electron has nothing to do with its quantum nature ("The electric field of the electron" doesn't even exist in the QFT description, and is only recovered through the Coulomb potential in a non-relativistic tree-level limit of the full quantum interaction of charges).